# Laravel ajax post with request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I can't use the `Request` class in laravel for a Ajax request and the input request.

I'm trying to call a ajax request to the controller and this works until I wanted to request the data that has been posted to the controller. This has somthing to do with the `Request` class that I use.

```
use Request;
```

This class is used by the Ajax Request

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

This is the class used to request the input.

The problem is that I cannot use them both.

```
public function postQuestion(Request $request) {
    //dd($request->answer);
    if(Request::ajax()) {
        // $answer = new Answers;
        // $answer->answer = $request->answer;
        // $answer->description = "Test";
        // $answer->Questions_id = 1;
        // $answer->save();
        return Response::json($request->answer);
    }
}
```

This is my code what i've wrote.
Anyone seeing somthing familiar? Or has a answer for it?

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure what you are asking? Are you not able to do `$request->ajax()` or `$request->input('myParameter')`?

Comment: Do you mean both classes being named the same? You can assign an alias to one of them if that's the case: `use Request as Request2;`

Comment: Ahh now I understand the question. Your namespaces are clashing. Just use a different namespace. e.g. use `Illuminate\Http\Request as SomeOtherRequest`

Comment: @Rainner Wauw! This works great! Thanks

Comment: @Rash and thank you too! I could't insert two names in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue turned out to be **not being able to use two classes with same namespace**. For such a case, PHP provides the `as` keyword.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request as HttpRequest;
use Some\Other\Namespace\Request;
```

then in code both these classes can be used. E.g. `HttpRequest::method()` and `Request::method()`

Answer (score 1):

you can use?

```
public function postQuestion(Requests\ModelRequest $request) { //your logic }
```

replace your Model in Requests\ModelRequest